# Issue with user input

Tags: javascript

I am currently creating a simple calculator program and have run across an issue with this line of code:

```
    var n1 = readInt("Enter the First Number in Equation ");
    var op1 = readLine("Enter the first operator ]");
    var n2 = readInt("Enter the Second Number in the Equation ");
    var op2 = readLine("Enter the Second Operator ");
    var n3 = readInt("Enter the Third Number in the Equation ");
```

The application gives me a "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" and cites the line right after the previously shown code. Is there any issues with the given code? Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in this "]":

```
var op1 = readLine("Enter the first operator ]");
```

Delete it and try.

Comment: Sorry but this did not work as the bracket is inside the quotations so it would not influence the actual code.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I thought that it might affect one way or another because I had not previously programmed a calculator.

Comment: But why rely on nodejs to build a simple calculator? You can use javascript alone to do this

Comment: like this : https://codepen.io/emozlove/pen/BaYydYo - It is very primitive, but you can understand the idea and try to implement it yourself